# Composition of homotopies of morphisms of complexes of abelian groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

Show that if $f_1, f_2$ are homotopy morphisms of complexes of abelian groups $C_n, D_n$, and $g_1, g_2$ are homotopy morphisms of complexes of abelian groups $D_n, E_n$, then $g_1 \circ f_1$ and $g_2 \circ f_2$ are homotopic.
We have that $f_1 - f_2 = \delta^D h_n + h_{n-1} \delta^C$ and $g_1 - g_2 = \delta^E h'_n + h'_{n-1} \delta^D$, and I tried to combine these two expressions in order to find something of the form $g_1f_1 - g_2f_2 = \delta^E h''_n + h''_{n-1} \delta^C$. However, I could never arrive at a precise formula written in this way (additional terms appeared that I didn't know how to eliminate). Can anyone help me with this? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean "if $f_1, f_2$ are *homotopic* morphisms..."?

Comment: yes, sorry i mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inspiration, consider the analogous situation in topology:

Let $f_1, f_2 : X \to Y$ and $g_1, g_2 : Y \to Z$ be continuous maps between topological spaces such that $f_1 \sim f_2$ and $g_1 \sim g_2$. We want to show that $g_1 \circ f_1 \sim g_2 \circ f_2$.

We start by picking homotopies $H : f_1 \to f_2$ and $H' : g_1 \to g_2$. We want to construct a homotopy $g_1 \circ f_1 \to g_2 \circ f_2$, so in particular we want to construct paths $g_1(f_1(x)) \rightsquigarrow g_2(f_2(x))$ for all $x \in X$. We already have a path $H(x,{-}) : f_1(x) \rightsquigarrow f_2(x)$, and we can apply $g_2$ to this to get a path $g_2(H(x,{-})) : g_2(f_1(x)) \rightsquigarrow g_2(f_2(x))$. We also have a path $H'(f_1(x),{-}) : g_1(f_1(x)) \rightsquigarrow g_2(f_1(x))$, and so concatenating these yields a path
$$H'(f_1(x),{-}) \diamond g_2(H(x,{-})) : g_1(f_1(x)) \rightsquigarrow g_2(f_2(x))!$$
These do indeed produce a homotopy $g_1 \circ f_1 \to g_2 \circ f_2$.

---

More abstractly: $g_2 \circ H$ is a homotopy $g_2 \circ f_1 \to g_2 \circ f_2$, and $H' \circ (f_1 \times \operatorname{id})$ is a homotopy $g_1 \circ f_1 \to g_2 \circ f_1$, so concatenation yields a homotopy $g_1 \circ f_1 \to g_2 \circ f_2$. To make this argument work, we only needed the following facts:

1. For any homotopy $H : f_1 \to f_2$ between morphisms $f_1, f_2 : X \to Y$ and any morphism $g : Y \to Z$, there is a homotopy denoted $gH$ from $g \circ f_1$ to $g \circ f_2$.
2. For any homotopy $H : g_1 \to g_2$ between morphisms $g_1, g_2 : Y \to Z$ and any morphism $f : X \to Y$, there is a homotopy denoted $Hf$ from $g_1 \circ f \to g_2 \circ f$.
3. For any homotopies $H : f \to g$ and $H' : g \to h$ between morphisms $f,g,h : X \to Y$, there is a homotopy denoted $H \diamond H'$ from $f$ to $h$.

---

So, try to prove these three things individually for morphisms between chain complexes and chain homotopies, then replicate the same argument! If you trace everything through you will end up with the explicit formula you want.

Comment: Thanks very much, we have that $g_{2n}f_{1n}-g_{2n}f_{2n}=g_{2n} \delta^D h_n+g_{2n}h_{n-1} \delta^C= \delta^Eg_{2(n+1)}h_n+g_{2n}h_{n-1} \delta^C$ and $ g_{1n}f_{1n}-g_{2n}f_{1n}= \delta^Eh'_nf_{1n}+h'_{n-1} \delta^D f_{n1}= \delta^Eh'_nf_{1n}+h'_{n-1}f_{1(n-1)} \delta^C$ so $g_{1n}f_{1n}-g_{2n}f_{2n}= \delta^E(g_{2(n+1)}h_n+h'_nf_{1n})+(g_{2n}h_{n-1}+h'_{n-1}f_{1(n-1)}) \delta^C$